# Find the youngest athlete to win a Gold medal

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have a dataframe loaded from CSV file which contains data from Olympics games. Goal is find out the athletes with minimum age who won Gold medal. I have managed to come up with following code.  Is this the most optimal way of doing this?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import min,col

gold_medal_df = athlete_events_df.filter(athlete_events_df.Medal == 'Gold')
min_age = gold_medal_df.select(min(athlete_events_df.Age)).collect()[0][0]
gold_medal_df.filter(col('Age') == min_age).display()
```

I am new to Python and Spark and I feel there must be some more optimised way of doing things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `pyspark.sql.functions` import

It's more common to use

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
```

since there are functions like `F.min` that shadow python builtins (`min`, `max`, etc).

## `collect`

It's not usually great to `collect` a result for filtering like this. Here, I would use an aggregate that I could `join` on:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = athlete_events_df.filter(athlete_events_df.Medal == 'Gold')

min_age = df.agg(F.min('Age').alias('Age'))

# do the join here
joined = df.join(min_age, 'Age')
```

You really could swap the initial filter into a `join` as well using `F.lit` in the aggregate select statement:

```py
min_age = (
    athlete_events_df
    .agg(F.min('Age').alias('Age'))
    .select(
       F.col('Age'),
       F.lit('Gold').alias('Medal')
    )
)

df = athlete_events_df.join(min_age, ['Age', 'Medal'])
```

Also note the use of parentheses to break up multiple lines. This is much preferred over the `\` character to denote a multi-line operation